# Would this question be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

We had a new user ask an interesting question over on Arqade: [Differences between real-life motorcycle racing and that of video games like MotoGP, Ride, and the like](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/254018/108003)

It's probably off-topic for us because it's focused on development, and it might be too broad for SE in general.

I suggested that perhaps this SE might be interested in tackling it. They don't have enough rep to ask questions on your Meta, so I'm doing them a favor and asking for them.

Would it be on-topic here, and could you give them any advice on molding it into something answerable?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

No, in the question's current form it's not on-topic here.

- The answer to "what are the  simplifications used in motorcycle road racing video game physics" is
  "it depends (on the game)," which is generally too broad, and even if
  a specific game were in mind, it'd be off-topic because we don't
  answer questions about how specific games implemented specific
  features.
- The answer to "are these different from game to game" is
  "yes," and yes-or-no questions are generally frowned upon as they are
  implicitly too broad (as the implicit follow up is "how" and the answer to that is "it depends").
- The  answer to the third bullet point is... you guessed it... "it
  depends." It's basically the same as the first bullet point.

A question about modelling the physics of a motorcycle that arose from a problem related to some specific (perhaps ultra-realistic) attempt at simulating those physics would probably be on topic. That is, "I am simulating a motorcycle *this way*, and it always falls over on corners I think it should be able to take" or something like that.

But I'm not sure that's really at all related to what the OP wants to have answered. I'd suggest they ask off SE, on a place like [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. Thanks.